# Distinct values in dropdown from JSON object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to exttract distinct values into a drop down list using the following code but its not bringing in unique strings, can someone help please?

function build_refinesearch_cancer_combo() {

```
    $('#combolist-cancer-type').empty();
    var list = [];
    var htmlResults = '<option value="-1" selected>Select cancer type_</option>';
    for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {

        CancerID = user[i].FKCancerTypeID;
        Cancer = user[i].Cancer;

       if (Cancer != list) {
         htmlResults += '<option value="' + CancerID + '">' + Cancer + '</option>';
        list = Cancer;
        }
    }
    $('#combolist-cancer-type').append(htmlResults);

}
```

Comment: And what is `user`? Could you make a fiddle replicating the problem?

Comment: Hi its the Refine search > cancer type on this page http://31.222.187.42/hca-consulting/Farm/index.html

Comment: Could you make the fiddle? Much easier to work on than a dev page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#combolist-cancer-type').html(function() {
    var ret = '<option value="-1" selected>Select cancer type_</option>',
        u   = user.slice(),
        arr = [];

    (function get() {
        if (u.length) {
            var v = u.shift();
            if ( $.inArray(v.FKCancerTypeID, arr) == -1 ) {
                arr.push(v.FKCancerTypeID);
                ret += '<option value="' + v.FKCancerTypeID + '">' + v.Cancer + '</option>';
            }
            get();
        }
    }());

    return ret;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BCW4p/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It *seems* like you want to keep a list of cancers already seen, and skip re-adding those.

If so, don't reassign the list each time. Check whether our new thing is in the list, and add to it if not.

```
var list = [];
var htmlResults = '<option value="-1" selected>Select cancer type_</option>';
for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {

    CancerID = user[i].FKCancerTypeID;
    Cancer = user[i].Cancer;

    if ($.inArray(Cancer, list) < 0) {
      htmlResults += '<option value="' + CancerID + '">' + Cancer + '</option>';
      list.push(Cancer);
    }
}
```